# WIX MSI uninstallation asking admin privileges

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, wix3.11

I am new to WIX. i have created WIX MSI file to do one custom action to add extension

```
<CustomAction Id='EXECUTE_AFTER_FINALIZE'
                      Directory='TARGETDIR'
                      Impersonate='yes'
                      Execute='deferred'
                      ExeCommand='CustomCommandToRun' Return='check' />
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="EXECUTE_AFTER_FINALIZE" Before="InstallFinalize">Installed</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>

<Package InstallerVersion="200"
                 Compressed="yes"
                 InstallScope="perMachine"/>
```

installation is fine but when i am uninstalling its asking admin permission

Can get what is problem with my code and any solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your custom action is also run on uninstall. The following condition would execute you CA always except on uninstall.

```
<Custom Action="EXECUTE_AFTER_FINALIZE" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT REMOVE</Custom>
```

Comment: But When condition NOT REMOVE folder clean up will not happen on uninstallation